# Does there exist a VBA command which does not change the formula of a cell, but its value?

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose in a worksheet the formula of `R4` cell is `=B1+B2`, and its current value is `10`.

A VBA command `Range("R4").Value = 5` will change **both** its formula **and** its value to `5`.

Does anyone know if there exists a VBA command which changes the value of `R4` to `5`, but does not change its formula, such that its formula is still `=B1+B2`?

PS: we can also achieve the same state in another way: 1) do a `Range("R4").Value = 5` 2) change the formula of `R4` to `=B1+B2` but without evaluating it. In this case, does there exist a VBA command which change the formula of a cell without evaluating it?

**Edit:** What I want to do is...

I would like to write a function, which takes a worksheet where some cells may be out of date (the formula does not match its value), and generates automatically a VBA Sub, this VBA Sub can reproduce this worksheet. The VBA Sub may look like:

```
Sub Initiate()
    Cells(2,3).Value = 5
    Cells(4,5).Value = 10
    ...
    Cells(2,3).Formula = "=2+3"
    Cells(4,5).Formula = "=C2+C2"
    ...
End Sub
```

Such that running `Initiate()` builds one worksheet with same values and formulas.

Without the VBA command I am asking, this `Initiate()` will be hard to generated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Well, the reason is complicated... I admit I am asking something wired...

Comment: @SoftTimur: But your solution makes no sense, unless you are into some sort of financial fraud. Tell us your **real** business problem, instead of an X-Y problem.

Comment: "you are into some sort of financial fraud" ==> lol, definitely NO

Comment: It is impossible for a formula to not match its display value unless calculation is set to manual.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a cell to something different than what the cell formula computes to.

Regarding your p.s.: You can probably change the formula of a cell without re-evaluation by changing the calculation mode to manual. But that would of course apply to the entire workbook, not just this one cell

EDIT: maybe a solution would be to temporarily save the formula of the cell in either a tag of that cell, or a hidden worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to change the result of a formula without changing the formula itself:

Change the value of of its argument(s).  This is a Solver-type approach:

```
Sub ForceDesiredResult()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("B2")
    With r
        If r.HasFormula Then
            .Formula = .Formula & "-5"
        Else
            .Value = .Value - 5
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well... Are you sure you understand my OP?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some very dirty code that will save all values of all formulas on the active sheet as custom properties of the sheet, and a 2nd sub that will mark red all cells where the value has changed from it's original value, while preserving all formulas. It will need some error-checking routines (property already exists, property doesn't exist,...) but should give you something to work with. Since I don't really understand your problem it's a bit hard to say ;)

```
Sub AddCustomProperty()
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim mycell2 As Range
Dim myProperty As CustomProperty
Set mysheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For Each objcell In mysheet.UsedRange.Cells
    Debug.Print objcell.Address
    If objcell.HasFormula Then Set myProperty = mysheet.CustomProperties.Add(objcell.Address, objcell.Value)
Next objcell
End Sub
Sub CompareTags()
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim mycell2 As Range
Dim myProperty As CustomProperty
Set mysheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For Each objcell In mysheet.UsedRange.Cells

Debug.Print objcell.Address
    If objcell.HasFormula Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If mysheet.CustomProperties(objcell.Address).Value <> objcell.Value Then
        objcell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
Next objcell
End Sub
```